# What does Room return if a query had no results

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Having a difficult time finding this answer and the documentation doesn't seem to answer the question.
If I have a basic ROOM query,

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM geotable WHERE geohash = :geohash")
abstract suspend fun getGeoTable(geohash: String) : GeoTable
```

and there is no such item that uses this primary key, what happens?  Android studio says that the DAO object will never return a null.  It seems that EmptyResultSetException only gets thrown when you have Single using RxJava which I am not using.  So what does plain old ROOM throw when it finds nothing?

Comment: ignorant question but why can't you just run this and find out ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Well it's going to be a few hours before I can get the code to compile again since it is in a work in progress state.  So it would be nice to know as I'm coding now if someone has the simple answer.

Comment: fair enough, i was just asking, i figured just running it or making a quick sample app/unit test for this would be a lot faster instead of having to wait here for an answer

Comment: My understanding is that the database will throw a `EmptyResultSetException` if there's no result. But what if there are multiple results? You'll only get one with this return type. Better use a list to handle all cases gracefully, especially since you're doing `SELECT *`.

Comment: @Nicolas From what I understand, EmptyResultSetException is thrown only the query needs to return a results, if its return type is something like Single in the RxJava library.  But I didn't see it for regular ROOM.  I could turn the result into a list, the geohash is a primary key.  Even though it should only ever be one item a list would make more sense based on the query.  So I would assume if it was a list it would return an empty list.  I could work with that.

Comment: Your query looks perfectly fine. If you sure there is data in your room database, may you made a change to the entity that you forgot to migrate. Otherwise it will be very hard for us to help since the info you are sharing is not sufficient enough for us to tell what the issue is, please share more info especial the func that calls getGeotable func.

Answer (score 20):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query) a fruitless query's behavior is defined by the declared return type:

1. `fun func(foo: Foo): Bar` would throw a `EmptyResultSetException`
2. `fun func(foo: Foo): Bar?` would return `null`
3. `fun func(foo: Foo): List<Bar>` would return an empty list

Comment: Just complementing from my queries, with or without a result your "number 1" never happens (no throws) and on your "number 2" it always return `null` if there is no result

Comment: Cool. A list is never null. My existing code base is littered with checking list result for null. I'll start slowly removing that nonsense.

Comment: Something strange happens in Kotlin projects. #1 returns null even if you specify the return type to be non-null. I suspect this is an interop issue because Room's generated classes are in Java. Tested as of today, Room 2.5.2, Kotlin 1.9.10

Answer (score 4):

If nothing is found based on your criteria, it will return null.

Comment: The function declaration is non nullable, should OP change method to `getGeoTable(geohash: String) : GeoTable?`

Answer (score 0):

By looking at how Daos code is generated in the respective *Dao_Impl, your Daos implementation should be contain something similar:-

```
final GeoTable result;
if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   ....
}else {
    _result = null;
    }
return _result;
}
```

So if there are no records in the cursors result set, the `_cursor.moveToFirst()` should return false and eventually result in returning a null.

Answer (score -3):

if there are no results
it returns nothing simply
and nothing happens

Comment: How does this answer differ from the answer already posted?